# Changing TOC Subtitles from CHAPTER to APPENDIX

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

[image]

I've added an image to try to help with my issue. According to my university format manual, I need to have "CHAPTER" and "Page" titling the TOC on every page of it. For the first page of the TOC, I added

```
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill Page\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{CHAPTER \par}
```

And then to get "CHAPTER" and "Page" to appear (as they do in the picture) on the subsequent pages of the TOC, I have in a .sty file:

```
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\afterpage{\lhead{CHAPTER}\rhead{Page}}}

\renewcommand{\@cfttocfinish{\restoregeometry\clearpage\afterpage{\lhead{}\rhead{}}}
```

This issue is that I that I need to change it from "CHAPTER" to "APPENDIX" once the appendices are listed in the TOC. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: A bit more information about your code would be welcome. For example: where are you placing the `\afterpage{...}` command right now? If you are using more or less a standard set-up, try using `\addtocontents{toc}{\afterpage{\lhead{APPENDIX}\rhead{Page}}}` right after your call to `\appendix`. Maybe that will work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @WillieWong Thanks for your comment, but this did not work for me. Sorry to be not be clear in my original posting, I have edited it to try to be more clear in my issue and with what I currently have. Thanks!

Comment: Your use of `\@cfttocfinish` suggests that you are using `tocloft`? Please [create a MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). In your case your MWE should include some dummy chapter/section headings, the `\appendix` command, and some dummy headings for the appendices.

Comment: @WillieWong I created a new question with a MWE and my intent is to delete this one ASAP. Please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614803/changing-toc-header-on-last-page-of-toc if you are inclined to help. Thank you!!