# Changing TOC Header on LAST Page of TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr

[image]

Hi! I cannot figure out how to change a fanchyhdr for the **LAST** page of my TOC. In my MWE (included below) you'll see that the TOC is 3 pages long. I do **not** want a header on the first page, but I **do** need a header on pages 2 and 3. The header on page 2 should read "CHAPTER" and "Page" but the header on page 3 should read "APPENDIX" and "Page".

I've used fancyhdr to get the "CHAPTER" and "Page" on the second page of the TOC but I can't figure out how to change the word "CHAPTER" to the word "APPENDIX" for the last page.

Please help. Thank you.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1.25in,left=1.25in, includefoot,paper=letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tocloft}


\newcommand{\doublespace} {
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.655}\small\normalsize
}


 
\fancypagestyle{fancyplain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{\partcontent}
  \fancyhead[R]{Page}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}


\fancypagestyle{myplain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{}
  \fancyhead[R]{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% TOC & LOF 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\partcontent{CHAPTER}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\doublespace
\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill Page\par}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage


\pagestyle{myplain}

\listoftables
\addtocontents{lot}{Table~\hfill Page \par}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{LIST OF TABLES}
\clearpage

\listoffigures
\addtocontents{lof}{Figure~\hfill Page \par}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{LIST OF FIGURES}

\phantomsection
\addtocontents{toc}{CHAPTER \par}

\clearpage




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Chapters
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{TITLE OF CHAPTER 1}
\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}

\chapter{TITLE OF CHAPTER 2}
\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\subsection{Another Subsection}


\chapter{TITLE OF CHAPTER 3}
\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\section{Another Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\subsubsection{A Subsubsection}
\section{Another Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\subsection{Another Subsection}



\chapter{TITLE OF CHAPTER 4}
\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\subsection{Another Subsection}
\subsection{Another Subsection}



\chapter{TITLE OF CHAPTER 5}
\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\subsection{Another Subsection}
\subsection{Another Subsection}
\section{Another Section}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Appendices
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{APPENDIX}
\addtocontents{toc}{APPENDIX \par}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix 1}
\section{Appendix Section}
\section{Appendix Section}
\section{Appendix Section}

\chapter{Appendix 2}
\section{Appendix Section}
\subsection{Appendix Subsection}
\subsubsection{Appendix Subsubsection}

\chapter{Appendix 3}
\section{Appendix Section}
\subsection{Appendix Subsection}
\subsection{Appendix Subsection}
\section{Appendix Section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `fancyhead[L]` at the end of the TOC. This will define the header for the page that is then current, i.e. the last page.

```
\tableofcontents
\fancyhead[L]{APPENDIX}
\clearpage
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a very particular case and therefore may require a very peculiar setup. For example, as you may add content to your final document, the ToC may change in its layout and the requirement for `APPENDIX` on the last ToC page may disappear.

So, for that reason, just use

```
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\partcontent}{APPENDIX}
```

for now. It updates `\partcontent` while still on the last page of the ToC and *before* the headers/footers are set. If the requirement changes, just remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

Werner's suggestion works well since you have only one page (the final page of ToC) where you need the header to be changed to "APPENDIX". If you have more than one page that requires the change, try the following:

After the line

```
\newcommand\partcontent{CHAPTER}
```

add

```
\def\switchapp{\afterpage{\gdef\partcontent{APPENDIX}}}
```

And, edit the line

```
\addtocontents{toc}{APPENDIX \par}
```

to read

```
\addtocontents{toc}{APPENDIX \string\switchapp \par}
```

Comment: The auxilliary command `\switchapp` is not strictly necessary, it just saves me having to type `\string` a lot of times.